# Split a large query (2 days) into pieces to increase the speed in Postgres

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, function, loops

I'm running a query on a database that contains over 120 million rows and 200 columns. The dataset contains loan information where we have for each borrower about 15 rows (one observation per quarter) and the borrowerID is also the primary key. I'm also joining on this borrowerID to retrieve information from the previous quarter, I understand this makes my query quite complex. The database also contains a FK (Foreign Key) on Bank. The party that hosts the DB explained to me that if I write a function to run the query in parts, by bank, it would be much faster. Currently my query looks like this.

```
SELECT a.id.   
   a.arrears AS "Months in Arrears",
   a.balance AS "Original Balance",
   a.bank AS "Bank",
   b.arrears AS "Next Months in Arrears",
   b.balance AS "Next Original Balance",

dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY concat(a.bank, a.id), ("substring"(a.date::text, 1, 4) || 'Q'::text) || round(0.3333 + "substring"(a.date::text, 6, 2)::numeric / 3::numeric, 0) ORDER BY a.date DESC) AS "Duplicate",
FROM loandata a
LEFT JOIN loandata b ON a.bank::text = b.bank::text AND a.id::text = b.id::text AND round((b.date::date - a.date::date)::numeric / 30::numeric, 0) = 3::numeric
ALTER TABLE myview
OWNER TO me;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE myview TO me;
```

Could you help me to write a function that this query is executed by bank or maybe it makes sense to do it per id, as it is the primary key? I'm running this view to download and store the data in Tableau.

Many thanks in advance.
Best, Tim

PS. The dense_rank function is there to find loans that have multiple observations per quarter.

The explain analyze results suggested in the comments can be found here:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/K19
I used a subset of the data where I selected 1 bank.

Comment: `PARTITION BY concat(a.bank, a.id)` This wil be disastrous. Is there any reason for not using `PARTITION BY a.bank, a.id ...` ? (similar for: `("substring"(a.date::text, 1, 4)` ) AND one more: `LEFT JOIN loandata b ON a.bank::text = b.bank::text` No need to cast here.

Comment: Please show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion: http://explain.depesz.com/s/K19

Comment: And the explanation is that the concatenation (and cast to text) will not allow the planner to use any indices. It will have to construct the fields, store the results, sort them and perform a mergejoin on them (since the volume is too large for a hash join) (and sort again ...)

Comment: Your query may _look_like_ that, but that's not your query is it? It's not valid syntactically.

Comment: It sounds like you're also giving the explain plan for a different query: "I used a subset of the data where I selected 1 bank".

Comment: You need to show the query that you're using to select from this view, and the explain plan when you do so.

Comment: `over 120 million rows and 200 columns` That looks more like a giant spreadsheet to me.

Comment: Indeed, this is not the exact query. I wanted to anonymize it a bit. I executed the explain analyze for a subset of the data, if I execute it without the where clause it will take ages. I can run the explain plan for the entire query but I'm not sure if that's as helpful?

Comment: No, the explain for the whole query will be just as ugly; there is no way out for the planner.

Comment: "Sort Method: external merge Disk" means that your work_mem is to small. What's the current setting and could you change it to something like 50MB or even 100MB ? SET work_mem TO '50MB'; Create a new EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure about the exact intention of the query, but using the date functions instead of computing in numeric types, and avoiding all the casts and concat()s will probably get you somewhere.

```
SELECT a.id
   , a.arrears AS "Months in Arrears"
   , a.balance AS "Original Balance"
   , a.bank AS "Bank"
   , b.arrears AS "Next Months in Arrears"
   , b.balance AS "Next Original Balance"

   , dense_rank() OVER (
      PARTITION BY a.bank, a.id, date_trunc( 'quarter' ,a.date )
      ORDER BY a.date DESC
      ) AS "Duplicate"
FROM loandata a
LEFT JOIN loandata b ON a.bank = b.bank
    AND a.id = b.id
    AND date_trunc( 'quarter', b.date ) 
      = date_trunc( 'quarter', a.date + 'quarter'::interval) )
        ;
```

BTW: don't use columns called `date`. It is a type name in SQL (it is highlighted in green in my editor)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest modifying this:

```
LEFT JOIN loandata b ON a.bank::text = b.bank::text AND a.id::text = b.id::text AND round((b.date::date - a.date::date)::numeric / 30::numeric, 0) = 3::numeric
```

... to ...

```
LEFT JOIN loan data b
  ON a.bank = b.bank AND
     a.id   = b.id   AND
     b.date between (a.date + 75) and (a.date + 105)
```

Although, T'm not sure that your date logic is what you want it to be. If you can describe in words what you want then a better method might be available.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks for the help. This modification is as fast as the one I already have. I needed to modify the date in your example to: b.date::date since date is stored as a character. Maybe this casting is the reason that it is not faster?

Comment: Using inappropriate data types is always a bad design, and often leads to performance and data integrity problems. You should get that corrected. In the meantime you might try creating an index on (bank, id, date::text) and retry the query.